# C# NPOI and sheet scale: how to set "scaling mode"?

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I'm using NPOI 1.2.5 with C# to generate some worksheet.

I need to set my sheet "Scaling mode" to "Reduce/enlarge printout" (see the last option of this LibreOffice screenshot)

[image: LibreOffice]

No matter how hard I try, my generated sheet always have "Fit print rage..."

[image: LibreOffice2]

I'm stuck on this problem since the last summer, so any help is really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`myWorksheet.FitToPage = false;` did the trick!